# python 2.6. unittest framework, asserts: help required

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.6

I am writing a test suite in python 2.6 using the `unittest` framework, and I want to use asserts in my code. I know that asserts got a complete overhaul and are much nicer in 2.7+ but I am confined to using 2.6 for now.

I am having problems using asserts. I want to be able to use the `assertIn(a,b)` feature, but alas, that is only in 2.7+. So I realized I must use the `assertTrue(x)` which is also in 2.6, but that didn't work. Then, I looked at [this document](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#deprecated-aliases) which says that in previous versions `assertTrue(x)` used to be `failUnless(x)`, so I used that in my code, and still no results.

I get the message:

> NameError: global name 'failUnless' is not defined

which is the same thing I got for `assertIn(a,b)` and for `assertTrue(x)`.
So I am totally at a loss for what I should do.

shorter version of my problem:

I want to be able to implement `assertIn(a,b)` in python 2.6.
Anyone have any solutions to this?

my code:

```
import unittest

class test_base(unittest.TestCase):
    # some functions that are used by many tests

class test_01(test_base):
    def setUp(self):
        #set up code

    def tearDown(self):
        #tear down code

    def test_01001_something(self):
        #gets a return value of a function
        ret = do_something()

        #here i want to check if foo is in ret
        failUnless("foo" in ret)
```

**edit**: Seems I am an idiot. All I needed to do was add `self.assert....` and it worked.

Comment: Could you please provide source code of your test case?

Comment: @RostyslavDzinko i can, i do not think it will help so much. one moment.

Comment: @InbarRose: Posting your code makes all the difference.... :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes. you are correct. i feel like a dunce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import unittest

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_example(self):
        self.assertTrue(x)
```

This should work, based on the docs for [unittest from Python 2.6](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/library/unittest.html). Be sure to use it as TestCase.assertTrue().

edit: In your example, set it as `self.failUnless("foo" in ret)` and it should work.

Comment: accepted you answer even though martijn answered first, because you dont have as many points as he does. :)

Comment: @InbarRose: Did you know that some people are worried that high-rep users always win when answering? Thanks for proving them wrong. :-)

Answer (score 3):

`assertTrue` should work just fine for an `in` test:

```
self.assertTrue('a' in somesequence)
```

All `assertIn` does is run the same test as above and set a helpful message if the test fails.

Comment: @InbarRose: yes, the `assert*` methods are just that, methods on the class. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your code for test case really helped.

Your problem is that you're trying to use assert[Something] as functions, while they're methods of TestCase class.

So you can solve your problem with, e.g. `assertTrue`:

```
self.assertTrue(element in list_object)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually implementing `assertIn` is pretty trivial. This is what I've used in my unit tests:

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase)       
    def assertIn(self, item, iterable):
        self.assertTrue(item in iterable,
                        msg="{item} not found in {iterable}"
                             .format(item=item,
                                     iterable=iterable))
```

You can then base all your testcases on this class instead `unittest.TestCase` and safely use `assertIn` even on python 2.6 and the error message will be much better than pure `assertTrue`. For comparison actual implementation of assertIn from Python 2.7:

```
def assertIn(self, member, container, msg=None):
    """Just like self.assertTrue(a in b), but with a nicer default message."""
    if member not in container:
        standardMsg = '%s not found in %s' % (safe_repr(member),
                                              safe_repr(container))
        self.fail(self._formatMessage(msg, standardMsg))
```